# Waiting for webpage to navigate and refresh

Tags: c#, winforms, refresh, webbrowser-control, page-refresh

I have been working on this one program for around 2 weeks now. I am having an issue with navigating to a page then refreshing the page. The issue is it will navigate and refresh but because it looks messy I want to trigger a "please wait" form

```
webBrowser.Navigate("www.thelineiamnavigatingto");
pleasewait.Show(); //shows the pleasewait form.
while (webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
    Application.DoEvents();
}

webBrowser.Refresh();
while (webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) //program Skips this
{
    Application.DoEvents(); 
}
pleasewait.Hide(); //Hides the pleasewait because the page is now ready
```

I can't really explain why I need to refresh again. I have looked into not refreshing the page so I have to do this. Is there a way to reset the "WebBrowserReadyState" I beleive whats happening is the browser loads and it then states that "WebBrowserReadyState" is there anyway to reset this back to notcomplete/waiting? - I am hopeing it's that because if it's the fact that this bit of code doesnt look for a page refreshing then I am not sure what to do next. So when I refresh the page and place same "While" loop below the first one - It skips it?

Does any specialist know of a better way to do this? or a fix for my code? I would be very greatful. 
Many thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the browser keeps its ready state because the refresh process is just too fast (or even immediate) for the same URL.

I think you aren't focusing on your main problem. You should not need to immediately refresh a page just after loading it for the first time. If you need that there is a problem with you web application, and now you have two problems. I would suggest trying to find another solution.

Good luck :)